# working on some symfony project and i just an error message

Tags: symfony, autowired

I am trying to send a mail in Symfony 4 with Swiftmailer but I get this error whenever I try to send the mail:

> "Cannot autowire argument $notification of "App\Controller\FoundController::show()": it references class "App\Entity\ContactNotification" but no such service exists."

Here is my `FoundController`:

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/found/{id}", name="found_view", methods={"GET","POST"})
     * @param Found $found
     * @param Request $request
     * @param ContactNotification $notification
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show(Found $found, Request $request, ContactNotification $notification): Response
    {   
        $contact = new Contact();
        $contact->setFound($found);
        $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contact);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $notification->notify($contact, $found);
            $this->addFlash('message', 'Mail sent successfully!');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('found_view', [
                'id' => $found->getId()
            ]);   
        }
        return $this->render('found/view.html.twig', [
            'found' => $found,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

and the `ContactNotification.php`

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\Contact;
use App\Entity\Found;
use App\Entity\Lost;
use Twig\Environment;

class ContactNotification{
    /**
     * @var \Swift_Mailer
     */
    private $mailer;

    /**
     * @var Environment
     */
    private $renderer;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, Environment $renderer)
    {

        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->renderer = $renderer;
    }

    public function notify(Contact $contact,Found $found){
        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Objet:', $contact->getFound()->getName()))
             ->setFrom($contact->getEmail())
             ->setTo($found->getUserEmail())
             ->setReplyTo($contact->getEmail())
             ->setBody($this->renderer->render('emails/contact.html.twig', [
                 'contact' =>$contact
             ]),'text/html');
        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
```

Comment: Is `Found` also an entity?

Comment: It seems to me that in symfony 4, `Entity` namespace are not created as service in `config/services.yaml` 

`
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Notification,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
`

Maybe you should create a specific services for this entity

Answer (score 2):

Symfony applications use a Service Container or Dependency Injection Container (DIC) to create instances of PHP classes, that have a service-like character, e.g. Swiftmailer, EntityManager or services you write yourself. An entity is not considered a service, it is often referred to as model. As such it is not managed by the container. Instead they are managed via Doctrine's EntityManager, which can either find (and update or delete) existing models or you create a new model on the spot and save it (using persist and flush operations). Since your `ContactNotification` is inside the namespace for entities `App\Entity\` Symfony's service autowiring will assume that it is an Entity managed by Doctrine, rather than a service.

The solution to your problem would be, to move the `ContactNotification` to a different folder and namespace, e.g. `src/Notifications` and thus `namespace App\Notifications`. This should allow the service to be autowired and then recognized inside the controller.

You can always check if a service was correctly autowired using debug commands:

```sh
php bin/console debug:container ContactNotification
```

or

```sh
php bin/console debug:autowiring
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer i tried and it worked